# Meaning of 長い間のロマンス in the song 四角革命

Tags: translation, song-lyrics

From the song 四角革命 by 相対性理論

> **四角カクカク革命前夜の**
>
> **長いあいあい間のロマンス**
>
> 近いカイカイ開戦前夜に
>
> やってくるくる車の行列
>
> 兎角カクカク革命前夜は
>
> 街のにぎわい恋のロマネスク
>
> 奇怪カイカイ開戦前夜に
>
> 迫りくるくる狂った結末

I'm translating this song and the bolded lines are confusing me.

Mostly, I'm not sure how to translate 長いあいあい間のロマンス.

Would it be "lengthy time of romance" or could it mean "long distance romance"?
The context of the song would lead me to believe 長い is referring to a long distance, but 間 is used for time, right?

Comment: Is it "ai ai aida" or "ai aima"? The former is  "lengthy time of romance". The latter is "long distance romance". (The rhythm seems the former, though)

Comment: "Aima" was not "distance" but "interval".

Comment: @user4092 I love 相対性理論 and it's "aima"! OP's transcription may come from [here](http://j-lyric.net/artist/a04f804/l0150e6.html), but I doubt it's a typo or something... (cf. [the actual song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mhik8nkFfR4))

Comment: Then it's あい あい あい間. However it's not clear what that "interval" refers to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E9%95%B7%E3%81%84%E9%96%93

As you can see, `長い間` is exclusively used for time, so it would be a `long time of romance`. I don't think its possible to interpret this as 'long distance'.